# JUnit Android studio initialization Error

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, mockito

I am fairly new to Android Studio. Excuse me if the solution is really easy; I am getting initialization error when I am trying to run my JUnit test.

Here's my JUnit test:

```
package mu.organyze;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import android.widget.Button;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


//mock creation
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class UnitTestForHomeScreen {
//
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<HomeScreen> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(HomeScreen.class);

    @Test
    public void checkLogOutButton() throws Exception {
        Button buttonLogOut = mock(Button.class);
        when(buttonLogOut.getId()).thenReturn(R.id.buttonLogOut);

        HomeScreen activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        activity.onClick(buttonLogOut);
        //assert continas after LogOut button is push
    }
    @Test
    public void checkStoreButton() throws Exception {
        Button storeButton = mock(Button.class);
        when(storeButton.getId()).thenReturn(R.id.buttonStoreData);

        HomeScreen activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        activity.onClick(storeButton);
        //assert continas after storeButton is push
    }

    @Test
    public void checkSearchButton() throws Exception {
        Button searchButton = mock(Button.class);
        when(searchButton.getId()).thenReturn(R.id.buttonSearch);

        HomeScreen activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        activity.onClick(searchButton);
        //assert contains after searchButton button is push
    }

    @Test
    public void checkRankingButton() throws Exception {
        Button rankingButton = mock(Button.class);
        when(rankingButton.getId()).thenReturn(R.id.buttonRankings);

        HomeScreen activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        activity.onClick(rankingButton);
        //assert contains after LogOut button is push
    }

    @Test
    public void check() throws Exception {
        Button storeButton = mock(Button.class);
        when(storeButton.getId()).thenReturn(R.id.buttonStoreData);

        HomeScreen activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        activity.onClick(storeButton);
        //assert contains after LogOut button is push
    }

    //    public void checkInputs() throws Exception {
//        Activity activity =  mActivityRule.getActivity();
//        assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.textHomeMessage));
//        TextView textHomeMessage = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textHomeMessage);
//        assertTrue(textHomeMessage.isShown());
//        assertEquals("What do you want to do?", textHomeMessage.getText());
//        assertNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.buttonStoreData));


        //        StoreData itemAdding = new StoreData();
//        itemAdding.editTextCount.setText("2");
//        assertArrayEquals(itemAdding.getCountItem(),"2");
 //   }
}
```

And here's my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mu.organyze"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    testCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    testCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.12.0"
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.12.0'
    androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
}






apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried solutions followed by other people such as:
Change my run config, changed imports in my JUnit file.

Error message:

```
java.lang.Exception: Custom runner class AndroidJUnit4 should have a public constructor with signature AndroidJUnit4(Class testClass)

    at org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError.<init>(InitializationError.java:38)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:111)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the initialization error.

Comment: Please add the exact error message you're getting in the question. Also did you connect your device/emulator before running the tests, and also ensure that your device was unlocked?

Comment: Updated post. Please check it out.